# If there is too many menu items how to gather them into collapsed menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar which shows category items. If the menu items exceed navbar how can I gather them into drop down menu with bootsrap 3.0

here is current navbar it shows only 10 because of view point. I have more items but they are not displayed. 
 [image]

depends on the screen size how I can gather them into drop down menu so it would look like this (I mouse over ALL CATEGORIES and menu appeared)

[image]

is there any way to do this with bootsrap css?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) which should get you started and give you a good idea on how to `nav-bar` classes work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0w2z9y6/1/) which you can have a look at. Of course this is a simple example but you can expand from this by using your custom css styling as required.